# Change integration order

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I am confused due to graphics

$$\int_0^2\mathrm{d}x\int_{x}^{2x}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y$$

well, for reverse order we have to find $x=y$ and $x=\frac{y}2{}$ as a functional limits for $dx$ but I do not know how determine number limits for $dy$

Plot does not make things clear:
[image: plot]

How should I handle?

Comment: **Hint** make the plot a bit bigger so that you can color the region of integration, for $x$ between $0$ and $2$, $y$ runs from the blue line to the red line and that doesn't completely fit on your plot ($y$ will run from $2$ to $4$ when $x=2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

complete the region and the plot becomes helpful.

[image]

---

We see that for $0<y<2$ $x$ we have $\frac{y}{2}<x<y$ and for $2<y<4$ we have $\frac{y}{2}<x<2$

Comment: hmm, strange, following your Idea I got $$[-2;2]$$ for $y$ limits in the buttom of the graphics :D

Comment: No. $y$ goes from $0$ to $4$, but the region must be divided in two  . I added to my answer.

Comment: Where did you plot the graph? (gnuplot seems to be bad for that) </offtopic>

Comment: I use: https://www.geogebra.org/graphing

Answer (score 3):

$\int_0^2\mathrm{d}x\int_{x}^{2x}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y=\int_0^2\mathrm{d}y\int_{y/2}^{y}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_2^4\mathrm{d}y\int_{y/2}^{2}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the domain of the integral is y-simple but not x-simple. If you want to reverse the integration order you have to divide the domain into a union of x-simples subdomains and then using the additive property of the integral with respect to disjoint regions.